# Adding filters to an Excel document using C1Excel(ComponentOne) and C#

Tags: componentone

Can someone show me how to add filters and how to freeze rows in excel using C1Excel(ComponentOne) and C#?

```
 //step 1: create a new workbook
                C1XLBook logBook = new C1XLBook();
                XLSheet logSheet = logBook.Sheets[0];
```

I have created XLSheet, but no property to add filters.

Answer (score 0):

You can create frozen rows using Frozen property as :

```
C1.C1Excel.XLSheet sheet = c1XLBook1.Sheets[0];
sheet.Rows.Frozen = 2;
```

However, currently creating filters are not supported in C1Excel.

Thanks,
Richa